# how to solve $x^3y′′−xy′+y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to use Frobenius method to solve

$$
x^{3}{\rm y}′′\left(x\right) − x\,{\rm y}′\left(x\right) + {\rm y}\left(x\right)=0,
$$

but it does not work. And the solution most be $y_{1} = ax + b$.
I tried also using first change of variables $\left(~s = 1/x~\right)$, and then applied the power series method but I did not get the $y_{1} = ax + b$ solution.
Does anyone know how this equation can be solved ?.

Comment: Try a power series $\displaystyle{\large{\rm y}\left(x\right) = x^{s}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_{n}\,x^{n}}$ and see what happens.

Comment: The solution can't be $ax+b$. If we put it into the original equation, we obtain $-2ax-b$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Can you describe how did you get that ?

Comment: Frobenius most likely won't work because it has an irregular singularity at zero. However, you can get a series solution at another point by substitution $t=x-x_0$.

Comment: Erm, just put in the equation. $x^3(ax+b)'' =0$ - easy to see. Then $x(ax+b)' = ax$. Now combine everything.

Comment: By the way Mathematica gives a closed form solution in terms of exponential integral functions. Solution is not a line.

Comment: @user119529 : The change of variable x=1/s is fruitfull. It leads to an ODE which an obvious solution is y=2+s. So a first set of solutions of the original equation is y=c*(2+(1/x)). Then, let y(x)=(2+(1/x))*f(x) which will lead to a separable first order ODE where the unknown is f '(x), integrable in terms of known special function.

Comment: If this is a homework problem, it may be worth noting that either $x^3 y'' + x y' - y=0$ or $x^3 y'' - x y' + y=0$ have much simpler solutions. So, there may be a typo.

Comment: @user2943324 yes i had a typo

Comment: In that case, you can see that $y(x)=c_1 x$ is a solution. Use that solution to construct the second solution by variation of parameters. The second solution is $y(x)=c_2 x e^{-1/x}$

Comment: @FelixMarin it does not help. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Hint: you can see that $y(x)=c_1 x$ is a solution. Use that solution to construct the second solution by variation of parameters. The second solution is $y(x)=c_2 x e^{-1/x}$.

Comment: @Nasser What method you mean?

Comment: Sorry. I had a type, here is what maple gives $(c_1 e^{-\frac{1}{x}} +c_2) x$    where I just used direct dsolve. `eq:=x^3*diff(y(x),$(x,2))-x*diff(y(x),x)+y(x);
dsolve(eq=0,y(x));`

Comment: @user2943324 Thanks for your hint.
What method i should start with?

Comment: Look in your book. In the chapter on second order equations, or possibly chapter about linear equations, there is a section that tells you how to construct a second solution of linear second order ODE

Comment: The equation looks something like $$y_2(x) = y_1(x) \int \frac{e^{-\int P(x) \, dx }}{y_1^2(x)} \, dx$$

Answer (score 2):

Another approach: Let

$$y = v x$$

The derivatives are:

$$y' = v + x v', ~~y'' = 2 v' + x v''$$

Substitute those into the ODE and solve for $v$ and then $y$.

**Update**

Upon substitution, we get:

$$x^4 v'' + x^2(2x - 1) v' = 0$$

Let $v' = w$, hence:

$$x^4 w' + x^2(2x-1)w = 0$$

This is now a separable equation, which yields:

$$w(x) = \dfrac{c_1e^{-1/x}}{x^2}$$

Using this result, now solve for $v$. From the earlier substitution, we had, $v' = w$, so we can integrat both sides, yielding:

$$v(x) = c_1e^{-1/x} + c_2$$

Lastly, from the original substitution, we have:

$$y(x) = v x = x(c_1e^{-1/x} + c_2)$$

Comment: Indeed, the sun was going down and was glaring right into the car, so the drive was lots of fun. Also, headlights look rather odd!

Comment: @user2943324 The second solution must be like this y2 = u(x) y1.

Comment: You will find both at one time using this method.

Comment: This is not VoP.

Comment: With the approach I provided, you do not have to guess at a solution from the get go and that is what I am trying to say. Of course, every method will lead to the same result if it works as the result is unique.

Comment: I suppose the guessing part is in $y=v(x)x$ as opposed to $y=c_1 x$ :)

Comment: Yes, but that is part of the strange world of DEQs! :-)

Comment: @Amzoti What method i could use to use your approach ?

Comment: @user119529: Did you get it?

Comment: @Amzoti Yes, i did thanks a lot.
But it is suppose to have 2 solutions y1(x) = ax + b and y2(x) = u(x) y1. And that we got looks like y2, can we extract y1 ?